# Why 2 Userforms Following the Same Initializing Mechanics Are Behaving Differently?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating two different userforms to amend data on a spreadsheet.  Since they will be pre-populated with information on the spreadsheet, I need to initialize them before display.  I was told that the initializing subs should be private.  But the macro is not reading them, so I change them to public.  Now, one userform is behaving fine, but the second one is still not loading.  It keeps on giving the following message:

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
>   Could not find the specified object.

What is the error?  Also, why can't I use private initializing subs like every one else?  Better yet, what is a good way in managing the various userforms?  Thanks!

**Update after Rory's comment**:  There are the codes in the main module

```
Sub AddLog()
    AddLogForm.UserForm_Initialize
    AddLogForm.Show
    Unload AddLogForm
End Sub
Sub AmendHeader()
    AmendForm.UserForm_Initialize
    AmendForm.Show
    Unload AmendForm
End Sub
```

It appears that error was inside the userform sub, but I did not see it because my error trapping was not set to break inside the class module.  Nonetheless, I'm still having trouble with the private/public distinction.  Perhaps this snippet helps?

Comment: The `Initialize` events should be private because you do not call them. They run automatically when the form is loaded. What line is highlighted when the error occurs? (note: you should set your error trapping options in the VBE to 'Break in class module')

Comment: When you say **macro is not reading them**, are you trying to call the `Initialise`? Like @Rory said, these are called when you load the form. You shouldn't be calling them. Also, `Initialise` should always be private. You could have a UDF that both `Initialise` can make a call to

Comment: So how do I initialize the userforms without calling them?  Showing the forms does not pre-populate them.

Comment: @Andy do you mean like populating a listbox or something? Also `userform.show` activates the initialize sub.

Comment: What actions are you trying to perform in the form_initialize event?  If you are concerned about the form showing before certain controls are set, it will only be shown before form load is done if there is a specific .show method called from within the form_load event itself.  Form_load doesn't complete, either, until form_intialize is complete.  If you are concerned about a second time load, yes, if the form was hidden after load instead of unloaded, the second time show is called, there will be no initialize event, so simply unload your form first.